# Masking latitudes and longitude area variables with not classic nc file with python

Tags: python, numpy, masking, netcdf4

i'm trying to understand climate data from satellites. If you want to see ncdump of file here:

```
netcdf NSS.AMBX.NK.D08214.S0740.E0931.B5312324.WI {
dimensions:
    nscan = 2495 ;
    npixel = 90 ;
    nchar = 19 ;
    nchan = 5 ;

// global attributes:
        :Conventions = &quot;CF-1.6&quot; ;
        :Metadata_Conventions = &quot;CF-1.6, Unidata Dataset Discovery v1.0, NOAA CDR v1.0, GDS v2.0&quot; ;
        :standard_name_vocabulary = &quot;CF Standard Name Table (Version 34, 13 June 2016)&quot; ;
        :id = &quot;NSS.AMBX.NK.D08214.S0740.E0931.B5312324.WI.nc&quot; ;
        :naming_authority = &quot;gov.noaa.ncdc&quot; ;
        :metadata_link = &quot;gov.noaa.ncdc:C00981&quot; ;
        :title = &quot;CICS Version-1 AMSU-B/MHS FCDR&quot; ;
        :product_version = &quot;v00r02&quot; ;
        :date_issued = &quot;TBD&quot; ;
        :summary = &quot;CDRs for AMSU/MHS water vapor channels and corresponding hydrological products are vital for the climate community. The corrections applied to the CDRs include geolocation correction and intersatellte calibration.&quot; ;
        :keywords = &quot;EARTH SCIENCE &gt; SPECTRAL/ENGINEERING &gt; MICROWAVE &gt; BRIGHTNESS TEMPERATURE&quot; ;
        :keywords_vocabulary = &quot;NASA Global Change Master Directory (GCMD) Earth Science Keywords, Version 8.1&quot; ;
        :platform = &quot;NOAA-15 &gt; National Oceanic and Atmospheric Administration - 15&quot; ;
        :sensor = &quot;AMSU-B &gt; Advanced Microwave Sounding Unit - B&quot; ;
        :cdm_data_type = &quot;Swath&quot; ;
        :cdr_program = &quot;NOAA Climate Data Record Program for satellites, FY 2016&quot; ;
        :cdr_variable = &quot;fcdr_brightness_temperature_1, fcdr_brightness_temperature_2, fcdr_brightness_temperature_3, fcdr_brightness_temperature_4, fcdr_brightness_temperature_5&quot; ;
        :source = &quot;NSS.AMBX.NK.D08214.S0740.E0931.B5312324.WI&quot; ;
        :refrences = &quot;Original level 1b data are from NOAA archive, they are also available at NOAA Comprehensive Large Array-data Stewardship System (CLASS)&quot; ;
        :history = &quot;TBD&quot; ;
        :date_created = &quot;2016-09-20T22:36:15&quot; ;
        :creator_name = &quot;Ralph R Ferraro&quot; ;
        :creator_url = &quot;http://cics.umd.edu/AMSU-CDR/home.html&quot; ;
        :creator_email = &quot;Ralph.R.Ferraro@noaa.gov&quot; ;
        :institution = &quot;DOC/NOAA/NESDIS/STAR/CoRP &gt; Cooperative Research Program, Center for Satellite Applications and Research, NESDIS, NOAA, U.S. Department of Commerce&quot; ;
        :processing_level = &quot;NOAA level 2&quot; ;
        :geospatial_lat_min = -89.86956f ;
        :geospatial_lat_max = 89.89485f ;
        :geospatial_lon_min = -179.9902f ;
        :geospatial_lon_max = 179.9998f ;
        :geospatial_lat_units = &quot;degrees_north&quot; ;
        :geospatial_lon_units = &quot;degrees_east&quot; ;
        :spatial_resolution = &quot;16km X 16km at nadir, 50km X 27km at limb&quot; ;
        :time_coverage_start = &quot;2008-08-01T07:40:51&quot; ;
        :time_coverage_end = &quot;2008-08-01T09:31:42&quot; ;
        :time_coverage_duration = &quot;P6651S&quot; ;
        :license = &quot;No restrictions on access or use&quot; ;
        :contributor_name = &quot;TBD&quot; ;
        :contributor_role = &quot;TBD&quot; ;

group: Geolocation_Time_Fields {
  variables:
    char scan_time(nscan, nchar) ;
        scan_time:long_name = &quot;Scan start time (UTC) in ISO8601 date/time (YYYY-MM-DDTHH-MM-SS) format&quot; ;
        scan_time:_FillValue = &quot;0&quot; ;
    double scan_time_since98(nscan) ;
        scan_time_since98:standard_name = &quot;time&quot; ;
        scan_time_since98:long_name = &quot;Scan start time (UTC) in a referenced or elapsed time format&quot; ;
        scan_time_since98:_FillValue = 0. ;
        scan_time_since98:units = &quot;seconds since 1998-01-01T00:00:00&quot; ;
    float latitude(nscan, npixel) ;
        latitude:standard_name = &quot;latitude&quot; ;
        latitude:long_name = &quot;Latitude for AMSU-B/MHS&quot; ;
        latitude:valid_min = -90.f ;
        latitude:valid_max = 90.f ;
        latitude:_FillValue = -999.f ;
        latitude:units = &quot;degrees_north&quot; ;
    float longitude(nscan, npixel) ;
        longitude:standard_name = &quot;longitude&quot; ;
        longitude:long_name = &quot;Longitude for AMSU-B/MHS&quot; ;
        longitude:valid_min = -180.f ;
        longitude:valid_max = 180.f ;
        longitude:_FillValue = -999.f ;
        longitude:units = &quot;degrees_east&quot; ;
  } // group Geolocation_Time_Fields

group: Data_Fields {
  variables:
    ubyte orbital_mode(nscan) ;
        orbital_mode:long_name = &quot;satellite direction&quot; ;
        orbital_mode:flag_values = 0UB, 1UB ;
        orbital_mode:flag_meanings = &quot;northbound southbound&quot; ;
        orbital_mode:_FillValue = 255UB ;
    ubyte surface_type(nscan, npixel) ;
        surface_type:long_name = &quot;surface type&quot; ;
        surface_type:coordinates = &quot;latitude longitude&quot; ;
        surface_type:flag_values = 0b, 1b, 2b ;
        surface_type:flag_meanings = &quot;ocean land coast&quot; ;
    float earth_angle_of_incidence(nscan, npixel) ;
        earth_angle_of_incidence:long_name = &quot;earth_angle_of_incidence for AMSU-B/MHS&quot; ;
        earth_angle_of_incidence:_FillValue = -999.f ;
        earth_angle_of_incidence:units = &quot;degree&quot; ;
        earth_angle_of_incidence:coordinates = &quot;latitude longitude&quot; ;
    float solar_zenith_angle(nscan, npixel) ;
        solar_zenith_angle:standard_name = &quot;solar zenith angle&quot; ;
        solar_zenith_angle:long_name = &quot;solar zenith angle for all AMSU-B/MHS&quot; ;
        solar_zenith_angle:_FillValue = -999.f ;
        solar_zenith_angle:units = &quot;degree&quot; ;
    float fcdr_brightness_temperature_1(nscan, npixel) ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_1:standard_name = &quot;brightness_temperature&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_1:long_name = &quot;NOAA FCDR of 89 GHz brightness temperature&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_1:valid_min = 10.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_1:valid_max = 400.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_1:_FillValue = -99.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_1:units = &quot;kelvin&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_1:coordinates = &quot;latitude longitude&quot; ;
    float fcdr_brightness_temperature_2(nscan, npixel) ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_2:standard_name = &quot;brightness_temperature&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_2:long_name = &quot;NOAA FCDR of 150 GHz brightness temperature&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_2:valid_min = 10.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_2:valid_max = 400.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_2:_FillValue = -99.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_2:units = &quot;kelvin&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_2:coordinates = &quot;latitude longitude&quot; ;
    float fcdr_brightness_temperature_3(nscan, npixel) ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_3:standard_name = &quot;brightness_temperature&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_3:long_name = &quot;NOAA FCDR of 183+-1 GHz brightness temperature&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_3:valid_min = 10.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_3:valid_max = 400.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_3:_FillValue = -99.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_3:units = &quot;kelvin&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_3:coordinates = &quot;latitude longitude&quot; ;
    float fcdr_brightness_temperature_4(nscan, npixel) ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_4:standard_name = &quot;brightness_temperature&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_4:long_name = &quot;NOAA FCDR of 183+-3 GHz brightness temperature&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_4:valid_min = 10.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_4:valid_max = 400.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_4:_FillValue = -99.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_4:units = &quot;kelvin&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_4:coordinates = &quot;latitude longitude&quot; ;
    float fcdr_brightness_temperature_5(nscan, npixel) ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_5:standard_name = &quot;brightness_temperature&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_5:long_name = &quot;NOAA FCDR of 183+-7 GHz brightness temperature&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_5:valid_min = 10.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_5:valid_max = 400.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_5:_FillValue = -99.f ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_5:units = &quot;kelvin&quot; ;
        fcdr_brightness_temperature_5:coordinates = &quot;latitude longitude&quot; ;
    ubyte flag_brightness_temperature(nscan, nchan) ;
        flag_brightness_temperature:long_name = &quot;instrument/channel quality flag&quot; ;
        flag_brightness_temperature:comment = &quot;The 8-bit quality flags are channel-specific. Users are advised not to use any scans for which the highest bit (bit 7) is set to 1. The lowest two bits (bits 0 and 1) are not used. The meanings of the bits are: bit 7 = Do not use scan for product generation; bit 6 = Calibration error; bit 5 = Time sequence error; bit 4 = Earth location questionable; bit 3 = Brightness temperature out of range; bit 2 = Lunar contamination warning; bit 1~0 = zero fill;&quot; ;
        flag_brightness_temperature:flag_masks = 0UB, 1UB ;
        flag_brightness_temperature:flag_meanings = &quot;good problematic&quot; ;
  } // group Data_Fields
}
```

I use panopoly for plotting you can reach it [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8pEig.png). And when i try to plotting with matplotlib i got same but when i try to get specific location can not be sure its right. Here my code for get spesific location:

```
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

file = './sample_data/NSS.AMBX.NK.D08214.S0740.E0931.B5312324.WI.nc'
data = Dataset(file,mode='r')

latlar = np.asarray(lats[:]) #Lati
lonlar = np.asarray(lons[:]) #Long
ar = np.asarray(fcdBT[:]) #Brigthness Temp

lo = ma.masked_outside(lonlar,105,110)
la = ma.masked_outside(latlar,30,35)
merged = ~ma.mask_or(la,lo)
ar[merged]
```

tried to logical merge two masked array in merged value, but it gives empty array but panopoly plot says there are value. Whats wrong here i could not understand.
Also **how can i be sure reached correct values when try to specific location ?** Panopoly does not support masking coord. or i do not know how to do. CDO does not work beacuse this nc file contains groups give this error message:

```
$ cdo -info sample_data/NSS.AMBX.NK.D08214.S0740.E0931.B5312324.WI.nc
Warning (cdfInqContents): NetCDF4 groups not supported! Found 2 root groups.
Warning (cdfInqContents): No arrays found!
```

Answer (score 1):

There is type error `merged = ~ma.mask_or(la,lo)` it should be `merged = ~ma.mask_or(la.mask,lo.mask)`